# How to get reference name of a prestashop order?

Tags: prestashop

I saw that the Prestashop's order name has a reference like `SHAJSUYD`, but how can I get this reference? At the same time I want to get the `id_status`.

I want to apply the `id_status` in a hook like this example:

```
public function hookActionOrderStatusUpdate($params)
{
    if($params['newOrderStatus']->id == 4)
    {
        my code is here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hook `actionOrderStatusUpdate` is called from this line (PrestaShop 1.6)

[PrestaShop/classes/order/OrderHistory.php](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/74e193d3a1f6d5a76201ce46b414033c8a7095a9/classes/order/OrderHistory.php#L105)

Which means that you have access to

```
$params['newOrderStatus'] // OrderState Object
$params['id_order']
```

When you have the ID, you can do the rest:

```
$order = new Order($params['id_order']) // Second parameter is id_lang, not required
$order->reference
```

`id_status` status you're refering to is in fact `$params['newOrderStatus']->id`

Comment: This can solve my problem but now how can i get the carrier and total weight assign for the order?